# Lost RIA Services debugging

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, web-config, wcf-ria-services

I just updated reference of my WPF client to RIA Services and somehow cannot enter to debug RIA Service methods.

So I cannot go to RIA Service breakpoints...

I have both project selected to debug within a solution...

It seems Visual Studio changed something under web.config...

Any clue guys why is it?

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that you have included ALL projects to debug and they have correct order.

IE Start DLLs first and after that EXE.